# How to compute the effective voltage across a DC motor driven by a pulse train?

Tags: dc-motor, duty-cycle

I'm driving a DC motor with a pulse train and effectively reducing the battery voltage to control the speed by adjusting the duty cycle.  Pretty standard.  What I'm unclear on is whether to use V_rms or V_avg for the effective voltage across the motor.

According to [this article](http://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/how-to-derive-the-rms-value-of-pulse-and-square-waveforms/), the average power across a resistor subjected to a pulse train is defined with the V_rms (P_avg = V_rms^2 / R).

#### TLDR;

```
V_motor(D) = V_bat * D
```

OR

```
V_motor(D) = V_rms * sqrt(D)

where
V_motor = effective voltage seen by the motor terminals, [V]
D = duty cycle, [%]
V_rms = RMS voltage of a pulse train, [V]
V_avg = average voltage of a pulse train, [V]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effective voltage for producing torque is the battery voltage times the duty cycle.  As you note, this is not the same thing as RMS voltage.

The reason for the discrepancy is that the formula that uses RMS is for finding the *power* delivered to a resistor.  Power doesn't cause motor torque, current does.  Also, a motor isn't a resistor.  The windings have a significant inductive component in addition to DC resistance.  If your switching frequency is fast enough, then the current changes little over a pulse cycle due to the inductance.  This is in contrast to a resistor where current is always proportional to the applied voltage.

If you switch slowly compared to the resistive/inductive time constant of the windings, then the resistance dominates.  In that case, the RMS formula (after subtracting the back EMF due to motor motion from the applied voltage) tells you how much power you are delivering to the motor, but the torque is still proportional to the average current, which is proportional to the voltage times the duty cycle.

The above statements may sound contradictory, but they're not, and are trying to tell you something important about driving motors with PWM.  Let's keep it simple and say the motor is stalled (so we can ignore back EMF) and we're trying to have it produce a certain torque.  Let's say you get that torque with 50% PWM.  That will be the case whether switching fast or slowly.  However, switching slowly will deliver more power to the motor according to the previous paragraph.  How to reconcile that?

Let's start with the fast switching case.  Each pulse is a small part of the time constant of the windings.  That means the current goes up a little during the on time and down a little during the off time, but this ripple is small compared to the average.  The motor is bascially being driven with a fixed current, which is also a fixed voltage related by the resistance of the windings.  All is well and makes senses.

Now for the slowly switching case.  The pulses are long compared to the time constant of the windings.  Basically the current is full on for half the time and full off for half the time.  The average is still 1/2, so the torque is the same.  However, the power is not.  Since the windings look resistive, the power is 4x the low-ripple average case when full on, and 0 when full off, for a average of 2x the power of the fast switching case.  Where does this extra power go?  To heating the windings.  This is exactly why you want to PWM motors fast enough so that the current stays relatively constant over the whole PWM cycle.

Still not convinced?  Another way to look at this is to decompose the current into its AC and DC parts.  In the first case, the current is steady, so the DC part is 1/2 (relative to what you get with the full applied voltage) and the AC part is 0.  In the second case, the DC part is still 1/2 but the AC part is definitely non-zero.  Now consider that only the DC component goes into providing torque and moving the motor.  The AC part at the PWM frequency just sloshes back and forth thru the windings causing heat due to their resistance.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply a pulse width modulated voltage waveform to a motor you do so because it's easy (these days) to make an efficient controller that doesn't get too warm.

But, what you try to avoid is the current through the motor being pulse width modulated too much. This means you use a fairly high frequency and the inductance of the motor makes the motor current look like the dc current when fed from a standard DC power supply.

So, the upshot of this is that it's the average voltage that is important and not the RMS voltage. You still may say "why" and my secondary answer is about power...

Power is volts x amps and if the current is a fairly constant 1 amp and the voltage is 12 volts DC (for example), the power into the motor is 12 watts. It's still 12 watts if it were 50:50 PWM from a 24 V supply - current would be 1A (with a slight hint of PWM ripple) and nothing other than the average voltage is going to be the correct value to give you 12 watts.

Comment: It might be good to note that power will be proportional to RMS voltage times RMS current *in cases where voltage and current vary proportionally*.  Since as you note the current in the motor should be relatively constant, that will imply that it is not varying with voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You multiply the source voltage by the duty so:

V_motor(D) = V_bat * D

Comment: Or the rms voltage multiplied by the square root of the duty cycle like so: V_motor(D) = V_rms * sqrt(D) as stated by the OP

Comment: Which are both V_avg.

Comment: Especially as the RMS of a pwm signal is... a * sqrt(D). ... So the "other method" is a * sqrt(D) * sqrt(D) which is simply a*D

Answer (score -1):

Why are you even using RMS if it is a pure DC pulse. A DC pulse is on then of for a time. and part of a period. time on time off.
Then in pure dc pulse, you would have time on against time off over a period of time.
So 50% on and 50ff,  with power on all the time, no pulse I x V= W, however 50/50 then the power has to use half the power.
But this is ok for pure resistive load, not for an inductive load.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).